# NULL character changing output file

Tags: c, file, byte, buffer

I have a function:

```
int csv_fwrite2 (FILE *fp, const void *src, size_t src_size, unsigned char quote){
    const unsigned char *csrc = src;

    if (fp == NULL || src == NULL)
        return 0;

    if (fputc(quote, fp) == EOF)
        return EOF;

    while (src_size) {
        if (*csrc == quote) {
            if (fputc(quote, fp) == EOF)
                return EOF;
        }
        if (fputc(*csrc, fp) == EOF)
            return EOF;
        src_size--;
        csrc++;
    }

    if (fputc(quote, fp) == EOF) {
        return EOF;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Basically, it takes whats in src and outputs the contents of src into a file(csv format) and the quote character will be whatever the argument you pass it is.

for example.

`src = ["name", "age", "gender"];
csv_fwrite2 (fp, src, src_size, '"');`

In the output file, it will contain:

`"name","age","gender"`

if:

`src = ["name", "age", "gender"];
csv_fwrite2 (fp, src, src_size, '|');`

then the output is:

`|name|,|age|,|gender|`

Everything works but, when I input the NULL character as the quote:

`csv_fwrite2 (fp, src, src_size, '\0');`
`

Instead of writing the contents of src into the file as strings, the output is something like:

`006e 616d 6500 2c00 6167 6500 2c00 6765`

instead of: `name,age,gender`

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does not `while (src_size) {
        if (*csrc == quote) {
            if (fputc(quote, fp) == EOF)
                ...
        }
        if (fputc(*csrc, fp) == EOF)
            ...
    }` print `quote` twice?

Comment: What program/tool did you use to see the output of the file?

Comment: Tip: "NULL" is best reserved to identify the _null pointer constant_ `NULL`.  For the _null character_, use `'\0'` or _null character_.

Comment: `6e 616d 6500` is indeed "name". But your editor is opening it as a binary file because of the non readable characters.

Comment: Its outputting hex correct? Since its a special character, is there nothing the can be done for the null character to be present?

Comment: @JasonPiao it is outputting correctly. It is just your file viewer that is showing you in this way. Remove the 00s and open again.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Ohh I opened it in a different file reader and its not in hex any more haha. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is the file, you expect, but it is loaded as a hex-dump and not as text in your editor, because `'\0'` is a special character.

Comment: So is there anything that can be done to keep the '\0' but not have the values to be loaded as hex? I need to support different types of quotes (double quote, single quote, and null quote)

Comment: quotes, commas, periods are readable characters. `\0` is not. So those you can keep in the file. Just remove the `\0`, unless you have specific reasons to keep them

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I have to keep the null character because apparently some files use Null characters as quotes and I have to support any file :(